# Python: evaluate by row in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to extract data from an excel (.xls) file and I've decided to go with Pandas as the library because it is allowed on my corporate computer.

Most information that I come across that describe Pandas is geared toward using Jupyter or the Anaconda ecosystem, and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to translate this to a traditional python script.

This is an example of a table I'm testing with:

```
        Date    a   b   c
1   1-Jan-19    100 200 300
2   1-Feb-19    101 201 301
3   1-Mar-19    102 202 302
4   1-Apr-19    103 203 303
5   1-May-19    104 204 304
6   1-Jun-19    105 205 305
7   1-Jul-19    106 206 306
8   1-Jul-19    107 207 307
9   1-Aug-19    108 208 308
10  1-Sep-19    109 209 309
```

My goal is to take the row with the maximum date, which would be today, and evaluate all of the information in that row as a dictionary or JSON, like

```
{ 
Date: 1-Sep-19,
a: 109,
b: 209,
c: 309 
}
```

(I don't care about the Index column)

I'm stuck at trying to evaluate the last row.  This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Path\Excel Pandas Connector Test.xls')
df = pd.read_excel(xls, r'Sheet1')

today = df['Date'].max()     # returns the max value in the date column

print(today)
```

I've found the max date, but what do I need to do to get the newest data out of that table using that date?

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
df[df.Date == date.Date.max()].to_dict(orient='records')[0]
```

This just selects the rows of your dataframe with the maximum value in the `Date` column and then transforms the result into a list of dicts, one for each such row.

From your question, I assume you have just one entry with the newest date, so you should be fine by selecting the first entry in the list. Just be careful about duplicate dates, as this will select the first that appears in the dataframe.

Hope it helps

Comment: Did you mean: df[df.Date == df['Date'].max()].to_dict(orient='records')[0]

Comment: Thanks I made the change that I commented above and put it into a variable to print it, your suggestion is exactly what I need and more concise than the path I was taking.

Comment: ```df.Date``` and ```df['Date']``` are two equivalent ways to select a column.

Comment: Ok.  df.Date  threw exceptions in my windows installation.